# How to find first char without adjacent duplicates in a string with regexp?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a sting and need to find first  character without adjacent duplicates. I wonder how to do it with regexp. Here is what i supposed should it be.
For example for string=`aabbbcddg` answer is `c`.

```
const paragraph='aabbbcddg';
console.log(paragraph.match(/(.)\1{1}/));
```

or

```
const paragraph='aabbbcddg';
console.log(paragraph.match(/[.]{1}/));
```

Can you explain why my solutions don't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern `(.)\1{1}` (you can omit `{1}`) matches 2 consecutive characters in the string and does not take the following character into account.

You could match adjacent characters from the start of the string `^` and then repeat that 1+ times. Then capture in group 2 the first character:

```
^(?:(.)\1+)+(.)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `(.)\1+` Capture any character except a newline in group 1 and repeat the backreference `\1` 1+ times
- `)+` Close non capturing group and repeat 1+ times
  (.) Match any character except a newline in group 2

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jyHuia/1)

If you want to get multiple matches and your string does not start with consecutive characters,  you can omit the `^` anchor:

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jyHuia/2)

```js
const regex = /(?:(.)\1+)+(.)/;
const str = `aabbbcddg`;
console.log(str.match(regex)[2]);
```

Comment: Try the string: asadaaasdfsdf

Comment: @Thefourthbird exactly, it should have matched the `a` in the beginning, instead it matches the *second* occurrence of `s` in the string, ignoring `a`, `s`, `a`, and `d` which are all valid matches for "single characters"

Comment: "not duplicate char "

Comment: Sorry, my title is deceptive, if you read post i meant without adjacent duplicates

Comment: @Mark Yeah, I got that, hence why I was saying that in `asadaaasdfsdf` the characters `a`, `s`, `a`, `d` from the beginning are all valid candidates here

Comment: @VLAZ In that case you can repeat the group 0+ times instead `(?:(.)\1+)*(.)`  `https://regex101.com/r/4XxqMq/1`

Comment: @Mark Do you also want to match the other chars as well? https://regex101.com/r/4XxqMq/1/

Comment: @Thefourthbird, I didn't want to, but thanks for example.

Answer (score 1):

`(.)\1{1}` matches two of the same character.

You could [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) all the `(.)\1+` to get all the characters which are not followed by itself

```js
let str = 'aabbbcddg'
let unmatched = str.replace(/(.)\1+/g, '')[0]

console.log(unmatched)
```

You could also use a `for` loop if you want to `break` when a match is found

```js
let str = 'aabbbcddg',
  found;

for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  if (str[i - 1] !== str[i] && str[i] !== str[i + 1]) {
    found = str[i];
    break;
  }
}

console.log(found)
```

Comment: It will work, but it is not an optimal solution with long strings since we will need to go through all of it's length.

Comment: @Mark since there is no wide-spread support of negative lookbehinds, it's not feasible to use pure regex for this, so you don't really have an "optimal" solution. Although if you want the most performant, then looping through the string and checking if each character is surrounded by *different* characters is probably the fastest you can get.

Comment: @adiga - I changed the wording a bit on your first sentence because I got what you mean but I think it was confusing "two characters followed by itself" also sound a bit like it's only matching `bbb` because the first two characters are followed by another `b` but is not matching `aa` because there is not a third one and I'm fairly sure that's not what you meant.